# Tracking anchor links in Google Analytics is not working correctly

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I am trying to implement tracking links in Google Analytics. I know this has been asked many times, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly (nothing is showing up in the GA suite). Ideally I'd like to specify a few links and buttons to be tracked/captured. I have this script in the header for my property as well as a function called "trackOutboundLinks". Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a better, more current way to do this? (besides Google Tag Manager). Thanks

```
<a href="#" id="cart-checkout" rel="checkout" class="button branding-primary-color-bg" style="">Checkout</a>
```

```js
(function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
  i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
  i[r] = i[r] || function() {
    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
  }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
  a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
  a.async = 1;
  a.src = g;
  m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-44871699-2', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');

//updated to track page query string and hash
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'page': location.pathname + location.search + location.hash
});

//Function for tracking links
function trackOutboundLinks(category, action, label, url) {
  ga('send', 'event', category, action, label)
}
//Testing it with the below event
var $cart = $('#cart-checkout')

$cart.on('click', function() {
  console.log('clicked');
  trackOutboundLinks("cart", "click", "logo", $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: Can you see `clicked` in console?

Comment: Nothing is showing up unfortunately.

Comment: Did you make sure jquery has finished loading before you used $?

Comment: I did ya. Thanks